# Where are device tree binaries after compiling the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I understand that dts are compiled during kernel build. Where is the output then? Inside the zImage?

Comment: output dtb is under the kernel tree in directoriey ./arch/<arch>/boot/dts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

output of *.dts compilation is in form of *.dtb files and are kept at the same place as source (*.dts). 
i.e. "arch/xxx/boot/dts/*.dtb"

Comment: Thank you. I think my confusion came from the fact that I'm compiling for x86_64 and I couldn't find the dtbs after make. In fact, I see dts mostly for arm but not for x86_64 in kernel source. How come x86_64 does not need a DT?

Comment: Becoz x86 uses acpi id based device enumeration.